# Radio buttons in Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I need to display radio buttons in my report. Based on the result from database, appropriate radio button should be selected. Until now I have been using just textboxes in the report Viewer.

Now I need to use radio buttons and one gridview.

Answer (score 0):

ReportViewer does not support radio button per say. The only alternative I can think of would be to use images of radio buttons, one for selected and one for not selected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks David. But How can i load the images dynamically. What i have done is, Embedded the two images in my report and dragged image control onto the report. Now wondering what to do..

Comment: It depends of the control you are using, if you are inside a table, I would suggest you set the image to external and put the path to the image in a property of your dataset, which would be to the selected radio for one and unselected for the others.

Answer (score 0):

in my problem I used it:

(change the textbox’s font to Wingdings2)

```
=IIf( Fields!MyBooleanField.Value, Chr(82), Chr(163))
```